# Full width non responsive CSS for mobile only and only on Woocommerce single pages

Tags: css, woocommerce

Ok so a project we are working on, we have a complex product table built within a product layout, but it's way to complex to easily make responsive, so I need to look at allowing users to have full width scrolling on mobile only when they view the single product page

Have looked everywhere and can't find anything that allows me to almost dis-
engage any responsive width on product pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for anyone that did want to the answers

Its' overflow-x:scroll;

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .single-product {
    width: 100% !important;
    /*width: 1200px;*/
  }
}
```

Please add above CSS to your active theme style.css file.

Comment: Hi how would this allow you scroll right and left, this would just make the size 100%

Comment: @user3593556 Set a static width and check ( width:200px; }